# PostgreSQL covering index and primary key

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I can't find it in the docs, but should I include table's primary key into covering index?

Query (simplified): `SELECT id, y FROM table WHERE x=5`

Index: `CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON table(x) INCLUDE(id, y)` or just `... INCLUDE(y)`?

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL, the thing which is automatically included in an index which points to the table row is the system column called "ctid".  The primary key is not included in the index automatically, so if you want it included you need to specify it.

But there is no reason to include it with INCLUDE, rather just put it directly into the index main column list `CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON table(x, y, id)`.  The reasons to use INCLUDE are if you want the index to be unique on some prefix of the column list, or if a column is a type which doesn't support ordering operators and so can't be in the main column list of a btree index.

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing `CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON table(x, y, id)` over `CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON table(x) INCLUDE (id, y)` ?

Comment: @tuk If you ever do`where x=... and y=...` you will get better performance.  So it is more flexible.  Also, INCLUDE is a newish feature, so using it gratuitously might cause compatibility issues.  Also being newish means it is less well battle-tested, but both of those arguments become less relevant every year.

Comment: "there is no reason to include it with INCLUDE" I'm not sure this is true. I've just discovered an index with Id and PhoneNumber and searching by phone number caused a table scan. Moving the Id to Include allowed Postgres to use the index for the query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an index-only scan you would have to include both `id` and `x`. Primary key indexes are not different from other indexes in PostgreSQL.